# If i start an array in PHP with nth index how much memory it will occupy?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create an array in Php by using index as nth number. 
For instance:

```php
<?php
    $A = array();
    $A['1000']='Some value';
```

Does this array will occupy memory for remaining 999 indexes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array in php associates values to keys. It is like an ordered map as you can find in the official documentation.

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
>   and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

This means that php won't allocate memory for the remaining 999 indexes.
Also, you can test it by converting the array to json:

```
echo json_encode($A);
```

This will return

```
{"1000":"Some value"}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, It will not occupy memory for remaining indexes. Here is a random example you can check through.

```
<?php
    $a = array();
    $a[1]=1;
    $a[10]='anyValue';
    if (array_key_exists(9,$a))
    {
       echo "<br>Array Key exists...";
    }else{
       echo '<br>Array Key does not exists';
    }
    echo '<br><pre>';print_r($a);
    exit;
?>
```

`Output:` 
    Array Key does not exists. (Which means it does not allocate memory for other indexes).
    Array ( [1] => 1 [10] => anyValue )